# how to use filepicker with angular?

Tags: angularjs, filepicker.io, filepicker

Trying to use angular and filepicker. The documentation is not clear.
Tried using it inside main html and it worked but as soon as i put inside a template it stops working.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try filepicker library for AngularJS. It is simple wrapper of filepicker JS library.

https://github.com/filepicker/angular-filepicker